# (WPF MVVM) How to add a user control to a View from a collection in a ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, view

I want to know how to add a user control into a window from a collection. Currently I am adding my control from my Views folder to a grid cell like so.

```
<views:MyControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"/>
```

I have an ObservableCollection in my view model and it stores a collection of user controls. In my view I want to take one control from that collection and place it into the cell of my grid. How can I add a control to the grid like I have done above, but from my collection?

e.g something along the lines of {Binding Path controls.[1]

Comment: "I have an ObservableCollection in my view model and it stores a collection of user controls." that isn't MVVM.

Comment: I have a lot of different user controls that the user can choose to add to the screen. The viewmodel has a collection of all the available controls in the application and also a collection of the 4 controls selected by the user to be shown in a view. The view is bound the to the collection of chosen controls and needs to show only the 4 that were chosen. What about this is not MVVM? Maybe I should clarify this in my question.

Comment: Because your ViewModel has Views in it.  A pure ViewModel could be placed in a project that does not reference any UI assemblies, such as PresentationFramework.  It should only contain models, and know nothing of the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If something contains a collection of user controls, it's not a view model.

A view model that backs a view which displays other controls should contain a collection of the view models for those controls.  You should be bind the `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` to the collection property, and then use template matching and data templates to create the controls.

So, let's suppose that you want to display a collection of `FooView` and `BarView` user controls in your window.  You will create a `FooViewModel` class and a `BarViewModel` class, and then create a data template for each in the resource dictionary, e.g.:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="{Type local:FooViewModel}">
      <local:FooView />
   </DataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="{Type local:BarViewModel}">
      <local:BarView />
   </DataTemplate>
</WindowResources>
```

Once this is done, any `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of these view models will find the templates, create the controls, and bind them to the view models.

If the `ItemsControl` you're using is a `Grid`, you probably have an additional step.  Any `ItemsControl` generates an item container (in the case of `Grid`, it's a `ContentPresenter`) to hold the views it's displaying; in a `Grid`, you probably need to assign the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` to that container.  Assuming that your view models have `Row` and `Column` properties, the way to do this is:

```
<Grid.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
      <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
      <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
   </Style>
</Grid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: While this is an extremely old answer, it is excellent.  I believe for the more modern WinRT, instead of having the DataTemplate be selected using the key and the Type property which doesn't exist, you would create a DataTemplateSelector instead.