# Add Custom control to stackpanel using Viewmodel WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a customcontrol, need to be added as many times when clicing on a button. This has to achived from MVVM WPF pattern. i have pasted my code here.  It will be great if you guys can help on this.

Please help me

```
<Window x:Class="DOCS_APP_ELEMENT.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:usercontrol="clr-namespace:DOCS_APP_ELEMENT"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:DOCS_APP_ELEMENT.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
<Grid Margin="10" Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Type:" Margin="20,0,4,0"></Label>
                <ComboBox Name="cmbQuestionType" Width="300" Style="{Binding ComboBoxStyle}" Margin="0,5,0,5" IsEnabled="False">                   </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                <Label Content="Question:" Margin="0,0,4,0"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="txtQuestion" Width="300" Height="50" Margin="0,2,0,0" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,5" >
                <Label Content="Answer:" Margin="7,0,4,0"></Label>
                <TextBox Name="txtAnswer" Style="{StaticResource TextboxStyle}" Margin="0,2,0,0"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="100">
        <StackPanel Name="myCustom" Orientation="Vertical" >
                **<!--<ADD CUSTOM CONTROl HERE>-->**
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <Border.DataContext>
            <viewModel:ViewElements/>                    
        </Border.DataContext>
        <Button  Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" DataContext="{Binding }" Command="{Binding Path=AddInstace}"></Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: do you only need to add the controls or are you going to present data in the control? If so I suggest using ItemsControl en datatemplates.

Comment: I am going to add an new custom control here. The custom control will multiple other controls.

Comment: I think the provided answers is going to help you enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it the following way:

have a `ObservableCollection<CustomClass>` in your ViewModel. The representation of your CustomClass is a DataTemplate with your above Markup.

Here's a full working example:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </Grid.DataContext>
      <StackPanel>
      <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="200">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CustomControls}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Border Background="Green"> 
                <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="I am a Custom Control"></TextBlock>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
              </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          </ItemsControl>
      </ScrollViewer>
      <Button Width="200" Height="50" Command="{Binding AddControlCommand}">Add Control</Button>
      <Button Width="200" Height="50" Command="{Binding RemoveControlCommand}">Remove Control</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
  public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
  }

  public class RelayCommand : ICommand
  {
    ... look that up yourself if you don't have a derived command class yet in your project... 
  }

  public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
  {
    public ICommand AddControlCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return new RelayCommand(x=>this.AddControl());
      }
    }

    public ICommand RemoveControlCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return new RelayCommand(x => this.RemoveControl());
      }
    }

    private void AddControl()
    {
      CustomControls.Add(new CustomControl() {DisplayValue = "newControl"});
    }

    private void RemoveControl()
    {
      if (CustomControls.Count > 0)
      {
        CustomControls.Remove(CustomControls.Last());
      }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CustomControl> _customControls;

    public ObservableCollection<CustomControl> CustomControls
    {
      get
      {
        if (_customControls == null)
        {
        _customControls = new ObservableCollection<CustomControl>()
                 {
                   new CustomControl() {DisplayValue = "Control1"},
                   new CustomControl() {DisplayValue = "Control2"},
                   new CustomControl() {DisplayValue = "Control3"}
                 };
        }
        return _customControls;
      }
    }
  }

  public class CustomControl : ViewModel
  {
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you please construct small sample.

Comment: As requested added sampple. HTH

Comment: Hey could you please give me your email id. So i can send my solution file over there can fix my issue?.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I won't fix your solution. You have got 2 (from my point of view) valid answers, which should point you in the right direction. Now push yourself, invest some effort and try to adopt the given hints into your solution.
If you encounter problems, don't worry and just ask here and you'll be helped...

Comment: In above example "CustomControls.Remove(CustomControls.Last()); " where is this decalred?.

Comment: CustomControls is an ObservableCollection which contains CustomControl items. The methods "Remove" and "Last" are inherited from the base classes Collection<T> and IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Thanks. the example given is working now. But my question stil there. Insted of adding textblock, i am trying to add usercontrol. How to do that.

Comment: Well, that is easy now. Add a namespace to your UserControl's namespace (if not already existing).
Then in your XAML's ItemTemplate instead of TextBlock write <usercontrol:NameOfUC/>

Comment: I need to arrange the controls in horizontal manner. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Set the Orientation of the inner StackPanel to horizontal
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>

Comment: Got that working. But for my case, I need to add controls to a Grid. Saw this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/6374557/1977871) but not able to translate this to my requirement. Newbi to wpf. Posted a question here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966460/how-to-add-simple-controls-to-grid-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

Comment: I have a single `UserControl` to assign to the `DockPanel` in the main view. Kind of sucks to have to use `ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>` for a single view control.

Answer (score 4):

To use the MVVM pattern you'll need a ViewModel that has a list of data objects which are bound to your custom controls. This controls can be generated by an ItemsControl. As I don't know your data I can just give you a general example.

**MainWindow.xaml (View)**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- instead of the TextBlock you would use your control -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs (View code-behind)**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs (ViewModel)**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> DataList { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        DataList = new ObservableCollection<string>
                    {
                        "Data 1",
                        "Data 2",
                        "Data 3"
                    };
    }
}
```

The Binding for the Text property has no path as the DataContext here is the string object of DataList. If you use complex objects, you have to use the Path to the property of the object (e.g. `Text={Binding Path=myProperty}`)

Comment: How to attach an my solution file here. So you guys can try it out.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. But I'm pretty sure our solutions will work. Just try it out and ask I've you got stuck somewhere.