# Get CollectionChanged event on Children's of any Layout control?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, children

***How do I get ItemAdded, ItemRemoved notification from the Children's of any LayoutControl?***

Let's say we have `Grid` Control. If I add new `TextBlock` control inside Grid, then it should notify me with the added item. If removed then it should notify me with item which has been removed from that `Children's (UIElementCollection)`, something like `ObservableCollection`.

Can this be possible ?

Comment: @kyle I'm trying to create my `own Children's collection` by overriding `UIElementCollection` & Setting `[ContentProperty("MyChildren")]` MarkupExtension on `overidden LayoutControl`...

Comment: Try to create your own GridControl with a property named for example UIElementObservableCollection. I Already did that by creating my own Concurrent Queue named ObservableConcurrentQueue,  https://observableconcurrentqueue.codeplex.com/ it should be similare.

Comment: Why not use datatemplate with observable collection? Use a listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to create your own `Panel`, there are some virtual methods you can override to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` in a subclass of it. But that needs you to re-implement the layout algorithm yourself.

```
public class ObservablePanel : Panel, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = delegate { };

    protected override UIElementCollection CreateUIElementCollection(FrameworkElement logicalParent)
    {
        var oldObservableCollection = InternalChildren as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldObservableCollection != null)
            oldObservableCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnChildrenChanged;

        var collection = new ObservableUIElementCollection(this, logicalParent);
        collection.CollectionChanged += OnChildrenChanged;

        return collection;
    }

    private void OnChildrenChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged(sender, e);
    }
}

public class ObservableUIElementCollection : UIElementCollection, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public ObservableUIElementCollection(UIElement visualParent, FrameworkElement logicalParent)
        : base(visualParent, logicalParent)
    {
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = delegate { };

    public override int Add(UIElement element)
    {
        var i = base.Add(element);

        IList newItems = new List<UIElement> { element };
        IList oldItems = new List<UIElement>();
        CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, newItems, oldItems));

        return i;
    }

    ...
}
```

If you know, you are only using Grid, you might subclass that one. But I do not see a way adding INotifyCollectionChanged to all the panels existing in PresentationFramework at once.

Comment: Exactly same thing, I was trying to do.. . But I was forgotten to override `CreateUIElementCollection` method.. Thanks a lot Wigy.

Comment: I am glad that this solution helped you. If you can afford the time to refactor, you would gain better testability from using the MVVM pattern. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8801715/1584012) to an unrelated question for an example.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but I guess you could extend the Grid panel and override the OnVisualChildrenChanged protected method to raise an event:

```
public class ObservableGrid : Grid
{
    protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);

        if (VisualChildrenChanged != null)
            VisualChildrenChanged(this, new VisualChildrenChangedEventArgs(visualAdded, visualRemoved));
    }

    public event EventHandler<VisualChildrenChangedEventArgs> VisualChildrenChanged;
}

public class VisualChildrenChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public VisualChildrenChangedEventArgs(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
    {
        VisualAdded = visualAdded;
        VisualRemoved = visualRemoved;
    }

    public DependencyObject VisualAdded { get; private set; }
    public DependencyObject VisualRemoved { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to build your own Collection control, IMO you should take inspiration from the ItemsControl implementation of Microsoft. 
The methods that you should check out are:

[private void CreateItemCollectionAndGenerator()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,56f4e535f8cbb100,references)

[private void OnItemCollectionChanged1(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,9311cc5427417fc1,references)

[internal void AdjustItemInfos(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, IEnumerable list)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,90452f60466837e8)

This class in general is a good study to understand what should be the thought process in implementing an ItemsCollection of your own, in the most generic possible way.